# Problems when installing git on my targets

Tags: ansible

I have some problems when I try to install git on my target node.

- 1st method: I used the ansible command

```
ansible <ip-node> -u root -b -K -m raw -a "apt install -y git"
```

and I have this error on my controller node terminal:

> E: Impossible de récupérer certaines archives, peut-être devrez-vous lancer apt-get update ou essayer avec --fix-missing ? )

- 2nd method: I played the following playbook

```yaml
name: This sets up an git    
hosts: vm2   
tasks:
- name: install git
  apt: 
    name: git 
    state: present
    cache_update: True
```

I get an other error

> fatal: [192.168.57.10]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (apt) module: cache_update. Supported parameters include: allow_downgrade (allow-downgrade, allow-downgrades, allow_downgrades), policy_rc_d, autoremove, force_apt_get, update_cache_retry_max_delay, fail_on_autoremove, install_recommends (install-recommends), update_cache_retries, default_release (default-release), state, autoclean, cache_valid_time, only_upgrade, deb, purge, allow_unauthenticated (allow-unauthenticated), lock_timeout, upgrade, dpkg_options, package (name, pkg), force, update_cache (update-cache)."})

My questions are:

- How can I debug the above errors?
- I'm not sure but I suspect my errors happen because my target node does not have internet access. For example, `ping google.fr` fails. Could this be the issue?
- What should I change in my target node network configuration to fix my issues?

Answer (score 0):

Note that you tried `cache_update`, it should be `update_cache` as the error message tells. Tip: the **package** module chooses the package manager on your target machines (apt, rpm, etc.)

```yaml
- name: Install git
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  package:
    name: git
    state: present 
    update_cache: true
```

Comment: Thanks. 
But i another problem. ansible say me i have not a permission to execute apt command on my slave node ( Failed to lock apt for exclusive operation: Failed to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/ : permission non accordée)

Comment: @IsmaelKofié https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html

Comment: I added the become clauses, you should have a proper setup for `sudo` and add -K to the command-line to prompt for a password.

Comment: @bbaassssiiee ,Thank you.

I'm not sure but I suspect my errors happen because my target node does not have internet access. For example, ping google.fr fails. Could this be the issue?
can i have you opinion about this ??

Comment: @Zeitounator 

I'm not sure but I suspect my errors happen because my target node does not have internet access. For example, ping google.fr fails. Could this be the issue? can i have you opinion about this ??

Comment: Why writing the same comment twice? You indeed need internet access to run apt.

Comment: Assuming that you don't run your own repositories, you need (proxied) internet access to install packages.